# Should I be converting to GregorianCalender and how in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to pass data into my server using an ajax call. There are 2 items that are being passed; a set of floats that are coordinates and a set of dates that are strings. On the backend the dates are XMLGregorianCalendar objects. Do I need to convert and then pass them and if I do how would I do that? Here is my javascript function that makes the ajax call:

```
`getResourceNetworkByAoiTime: function(aoi,dateRange){


 var AreaOfInterest  = {eastLon:aoi[0],westLon: aoi[1],southLat:aoi[2],northLat:aoi[3]  };

  var LocalDateTimeRange ={start:dateRange[0],end:dateRange[1]};
  //var JData = {{eastLon:aoi[0],westLon: aoi[1],southLat:aoi[2],northLat:aoi[3]},{start:dateRange[0],end:dateRange[1]}};

  var DTO ={};
   DTO.AreaOfInterest = AreaOfInterest;
   DTO.LocalDateTimeRange =LocalDateTimeRange ;
     var self = this;
     $.ajax({
         cache: false,
         url: cdpeConfig.edcssUrl+"getAllResourceNetworksByAoiAndTime2/",
         type: 'GET',
         contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
        data:JSON.stringify(DTO),
       // data:jsonarg1+jsonarg2,
         success: function(data) {
          Alertify.dialog.alert('Successful AJAX resource network');
         }
       }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         sandbox.emit('error', { action: 'initialError', jqXHR: jqXHR });
       });
 }`
```

Here is the method that the javascript is calling:

```
public  List <ResourceNetwork> getAllResourceNetworksByAoiAndTime2(GetAllResourceNetworksByAoiAndTime aoi_dateRange){
ResourceNetworkServiceService resourcenetwork_service_service = new ResourceNetworkServiceService();
ResourceNetworkService resource_service resourcenetwork_service_service.getResourceNetworkServicePort();
List<ResourceNetwork> resource_networks = null;
AreaOfInterest aoi = new AreaOfInterest();
LocalDateTimeRange date_range = new LocalDateTimeRange();
aoi.setEastLon(aoi_dateRange.getArg0().getEastLon());
aoi.setWestLon(aoi_dateRange.getArg0().getWestLon());
aoi.setSouthLat(aoi_dateRange.getArg0().getSouthLat());
aoi.setNorthLat(aoi_dateRange.getArg0().getNorthLat());
date_range.setStart(aoi_dateRange.getArg1().getStart());
date_range.setEnd(aoi_dateRange.getArg1().getEnd());
resource_networks = resource_service.getAllResourceNetworksByAoiAndTime(aoi, date_range);
return resource_networks;
}
```

Thanks for all help!

Comment: These are the parameters as seen in the debugger of the broswer
    `AreaOfInterest[eastLon] 29.38216,
    AreaOfInterest[northLat] 50.847572,
    AreaOfInterest[southLat] 29.38216,
    AreaOfInterest[westLon] -121.113228,
    LocalDateTimeRange[end] 2009-05-27T23:00:00Z,
    LocalDateTimeRange[start] 2009-05-25T00:00:00Z,
_ 1425488522744`
This is the response in the debugger in the browser
    `No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@62dfb013; line: 1, column: 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume aoi_dateRange.getArg1().getStart() and aoi_dateRange.getArg1().getEnd() are supposed to return XMLGregorianCalendar objects resulting from the conversion of the strings passed from the client to the server.

The string representation of XMLGregorianCalendar objects is described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toXMLFormat()
http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation

for example, the following string should be valid (not tested):

2002-10-10T17:00:00Z

If time is formatted according to the lexical representation as described in the w3c spec, this should work (imho).

Comment: I tried that, still a 400 error. I tried changing `contentType:` to `contentType: text/xml` and got a 500 error so maybe its the java side?

Comment: OMG, it looks like you are sending JSON, but the server expects XML. Changing the content type will not help unless you change the content itself, too. Sorry for overlooking this. Do you have a code fragment that contains the annotated JAX-RS resource? How is the function on the server side embedded (i.e. how is it invoked)? Which Tomcat version are you using? I see you issue a GET request with a body, which is imho kind of unusual. Typically, you either have a GET request with URL parameters only, or a POST request with a body (either XML or JSON).

Comment: the problem was not on my side it was on the service provider side